# How to make xshift and yshift compatible with redefined units in TikZ when using nested scopes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am writing some code with nested scopes that have various transformations applied within them. In particular, I have nested scopes of the form `\begin{scope}[x={(a,b)},y={(c,d)}]` redefining the units of the coordinate system, as well as transformations of the form `\begin{scope}[xshift=a,yshift=b]`.

Now, either of these things seem to commute with *themselves* nicely; if I try

```
\begin{scope}[x={(2,0)},y={(0.5,2)}]
    %code A
    \begin{scope}[x={(2,0)},y={(0.5,2)}]
        %code B
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
```

then `code A` will be drawn with an x-vector of (2,0) and a y-vector of (1,2). (I think this is because the `y={(0.5,2)}` comes after the redefinition of `x`, and so the `0.5` coefficient is applied to the `x` vector.) Meanwhile, `code B` will be drawn with an x-vector of (4,0) and a y-vector of (4,4), which is what I would expect from composing these two transformation matrices.

Likewise, composing `shift` transformations acts how I would expect.

Where I run into trouble, though, is combining the two.

```
\newcommand{\exampleshape}{
\draw[fill=red!20](0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=green!20](0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,0.5) -- cycle;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
\exampleshape

\begin{scope}[y={(0,2)}]
    \begin{scope}[yshift=1cm]
        \exampleshape
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
```

[image]

I would expect that the second scope here "believes" `y` to be the vector (0,2), and so applying a `yshift` of 1 should shift the picture up by 2 units in the underlying coordinate system. Instead, it seems that the `yshift` is performed relative to absolute coordinates.

Why doesn't this happen, and what should I do to get the desired behavior? (Obviously in this case I can manually adjust things, but in practice I am working with much more complicated nested scopes and this is not so feasible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TikZ there are two types of operations: some are affected by transformations, some are not. The former are for the general drawing, the latter are for adjustments, labels etc. `xshift` and `yshift` belong to the second group, while `shift` belongs the first one. So, instead of `yshift=1cm`, use `shift={(0,1)}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\exampleshape}{
  \draw[fill=red!20](0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=green!20](0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,0.5) -- cycle;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
\exampleshape
\begin{scope}[y={(0,2)},shift={(0,1)}]
  \exampleshape
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```